# for loop serialization and wait

Tags: bash-scripting

I need to copy over x amount of directories using aws's snowball client. However, since the client hogs quite a bit of resources, i'd like to serial each execution so that it runs 1 at a time and will wait for the previous copy to complete.

This is the script i have

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for d in $(find $PWD -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '20*' -not -name '2019-Q1');do

snowball cp -r --batchFileSizeInKBLimit=200000 --batchNumOfFiles=100000 ${d} s3://bucketname/dirname/$(basename ${d})"

done
```

how can I ensure the copy completes before the next one starts?
I am thinking 'wait $1' but idk if that will work here.

Comment: Hi romedawg, Just a suggestion you may try. You can use `sleep <time_in_sec>` in the script. And to get an idea of time, try copying 4-5 files (one at a time including at least 1 file with minimum size and 1 with max size) manually and see how much time on average it takes. Use this : **`time snowball cp <rest_of_command>`**

Comment: Thanks C0deDaedalus, I appreciate the response!  I ended up forgoing the wait command.  It executed one at a time and completed how I needed it to.  But time will be helpful to monitor moving forward.